# How can I check a false condition in python

Tags: python

I have a very simple beginner's question. I'm using python to re-write a php script on the server and I don't know how to translate this php code to python:

```
if(a && b && c && (!d || !e) doThis()
```

For python I only know how to do it the other way around

```
if a and b and c and (d or e):
    doThis(etc)
```

How can I check `**NOT** d` or `**NOT** e`?

Comment: `if not a and not b and not c: doThis()`?

Comment: I can't help but feel this is something that could have been easily googled.

Comment: `&` and `|` are **binary and operators**, not boolean operators. Use `and` and `or`.

Comment: I'm guessing that the missing `)` in the if-statement is just a typo here on SO? Otherwise, it's quite easy write broken code in Python as well ;-)

Comment: @apokryfos I googled it and I couldn't find the answer plus it's midnight here. No need to be rude. Some people are working really hard 24/7.

Comment: You can use `not`. Like:

    if a and b and c and (not d or not e):
        doThis(etc)

Saying `not [variable name]` returns True if the variable doesn't exist. For example: 

    if not a:
       print("test")
Will print `test`.

Comment: @Ditto you can't assume that others of us are not working hard.

Comment: No need for a search engine, just look at the documentation: [Boolean operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry, buddy. Not time for this. I'm trying to finish this thing. Have a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways, and there are many other post out there that you just needed to do a simple google search to find.

```
if not a and not b and not c: 
    doThis()
```

Comment: If the person is to google, then why not do so yourself and flag the post as a duplicate next time?

Comment: I can do this right? if not(a or b or c): doThis()

Comment: ``not`` worked. Thank you. I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: @abccd: Yes you can do `not(a or b or c)` but I'm sure it won't do what you think.

Comment: it mean that if one of `a or b or c` is True, not that would be False. Therefore if none of `a or b or c` is True, not that would be considered True